# Determining how many cards of a Poker hand to discard

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, poker

I am programming a game of 5 Card Poker, and an AI to play it. I have written a function that calculates, for a given card in a hand, the probability of improving the hand if this card is discarded and swapped for another random card dealt from the deck. As of now, the probability is calculated on the assumption that all other 47 cards are still in the deck. This will be refined at a later stage.

I now need to write a function that determines which, and how many (0, 1, 2, or 3) cards to discard from a hand.

1. If I have the probability for each of the 5 cards, what is the best way to determine what combination (of up to 3) of these cards will give the largest possibility in improving the hand?
2. What would be a suitable way to determine, based on this accumulated probability, if the cards should actually be discarded or not?

Comment: Well, it sounds like you need more than just "the probability of improving the hand".  You need to know something akin to the expected gain on the hand.    That is to say, you should have some ranking of the hands (maybe by inverse probability ?)  so that you can quantify what you mean by "improving".  Then you need to generalize your function to do the same thing for $2$ swapped cards, and $3$.  After that, I'd say you should do the thing that had the best expected value...but I suppose you might want to look at more subtle utility functions.

Comment: if you discard 3 cards, then you will receive back one of something like 16,000 combinations of new cards - check each case to see if the hand is better or worse - that's within the limits of today's computing

Comment: Just to say:  usually these sort of things are done by sampling, rather than any sort of analysis....if for no other reason than that the depletion of the deck tends to rule out any sort of pleasant counting.

Comment: @lulu I think I am already halfway there to what you are suggesting. My code works by using an algorithm that creates a unique binary value for any possible hand and this number is determined in such a way (by considering the type of hand, card values, etc.) that a larger binary valued hand will beat/ is better than a lower valued one

Comment: @cato that is similar to how my probability is calculated for each individual hand - in a simplified way of aying it, it creates a new hand by replacing the card in question with each other possible one and counts how many of these new hands are better than the current one

Answer (score 0):

But the objective is not just to improve but to improve to the best hand.

A 2 has the same chance to improve as Ace

Improve to the best possible hand is also not correct as would always draw for a straight flush

As for what to discard.  The cards that don't make the hand.

- Keep any 5 card hand (straight, flush, boat)
- Keep quads
- Keep trips
- Keep 2 pairs
- Keep 1 pair JJ+
- Keep any 4 flush or 4 straight
- Keep any Ax suited
- Keep any pair
- Keep suited connector 5 or higher or 1 gap suited
- Keep 2 biggest cards if bigger than 7
- Keep un-suited connector 5 or higher or 1 gap suited
- Keep top two cards

If you have to pay to continue then many hands should be folded